# PostGIS schemas don't show in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I try to use QGIS to display some data stored in PostGIS, some of the schemas don't show except public; and it's a testing database, so I have only one super user: postgres. I use PostgreSQL9.3.

Anyone has some suggestion?

Comment: Which schemas do you not see you are expecting to see? Does it have a table that has a geometry column?

Comment: I found the reason, it's because other schema is empty or there's no vector data inside. Previous I load a raster data into a schema named scratch, once I added a vector data, it shows in QGIS.

Comment: @Allen, please move your "comment" above to an "answer" below and, once StakExchange allows you (I think after 2 days), you can mark your answer as "Accepted" (hit the checkmark next to the answer) to close out this question.  Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to move this answer to below because i ask the question and answer the question within a certain time.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason, it's because other schema is empty or there's no vector data inside. Previous I load a raster data into a schema named scratch

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new database connection, you can check `Only look in schema public`, or leave it unchecked.

You can change this later if you edit the connection (unless there are no other schemas, then the entry is greyed out).